# putting limits to x,y,z interpolated heatmap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking to plot a heatmap for which I have the value (=heatmap color) z at each couple of spatial x,y coordinates but I want to mark out the z values between [z0,z1] with z0=0.0 and z1=0.4 while some of interpolated z values are under and above those boundaries.

```
from numpy.random import uniform, seed
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# make up data.
#npts = int(raw_input('enter # of random points to plot:'))
seed(0)
npts = 200
x = uniform(-2, 2, npts)
y = uniform(-2, 2, npts)
z = x*np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)
# define grid.
xi = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
yi = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)
# grid the data.
zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')
# contour the gridded data, plotting dots at the nonuniform data points.
CS = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 15, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
                  vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max())
plt.colorbar()  # draw colorbar
# plot data points.
plt.show()
```

[image]
I would like to restrict the colorbar and heatmap color from 0.0 to 0.4 (so avoid in the heatmap and in the colorbar valies under 0.0 and above 0.4). 
How to do that? Thanks

Comment: What color should values in your `z` array appear in the heatmap if they are outside the range `(0,0.4)`?

Comment: in fact in my true data (here is an example), there's no values under 0.0 and upper than 0.4. Only values like 0.0125*10-312 ... so I suppose that heatmap extrapolate values/colors under and upper my input values (by a kernel method) ? That's a real question for me to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the values in a numpy array to `None` to leave them unplotted. For example,

```
zmin = 0.0
zmax = 0.4
zi[(zi<zmin) | (zi>zmax)] = None
CS = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 15, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
                  vmax=zmax, vmin=zmin)
```

[image]