# Make a heatmap of x,y,z data in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to draw a heatmap in Python.
I have studied several tutorials but still can't achieve what I need.
My data has 3 columns: **X**, **Y** (coordinates in the scatterplot) and **cluster** (a group/cluster each row is placed). The desired output should look like that (6 clusters and X,Y points distributed in the coloured areas):

[image]

My current code:

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kde
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Get the data (csv file is hosted on the web)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ampil/sandbox/master/latest-sales-sample.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep = ';')
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
# create data
x = df['X']
y = np.log(df['Y'])
z = df['cluster']

# target grid to interpolate to
xi = yi = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

# interpolate
zi = griddata((x,y),z,(xi,yi),method='cubic')

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis((x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01), cmap='coolwarm')
plt.plot(x,y,'k.')
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=16)
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

gives me

[image: my graph]

Later on, I plan to publish the graph via dash.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is a small edit to answer provided by warped.

The difference is the inclusion of the parameter 'extend' in the contourf method call.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html

For some more information about the minimum/maximum color-map behaviour, see:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contourf-demo-py

```
# libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kde
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# Get the data (csv file is hosted on the web)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ampil/sandbox/master/latest-sales-sample.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep = ';')
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
# create data
x = df['X']
y = np.log(df['Y'])
z = df['cluster']

#following 2 lines provided by user-warped
xi = np.arange(0, np.max(x), 0.1)
yi = np.arange(0, np.max(y), 0.1)

xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)

# interpolate
zi = griddata((x,y),z,(xi,yi),method='cubic')

#define color map...which you can choose to modify with 'set_under' and 'set_over'
#as per: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contourf-demo-py
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap("coolwarm")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis((x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))

#added the 'extend' parameter to user:warped edit as per documentation of plt.contourf
#https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=[1,2,3,4,5,6], cmap=cmap, extend='both')
plt.plot(x, y,'k.')

plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

[image: result image]

As far as extending the colours beyond what they are now...you'd get a result that would look very different from the main area and would likely have little meaning. If this were a GIS application, I would have those exterior pixels to be "NODATA".

EDIT:
Providing evidence that filling the exterior would look strange...

Using a canned gdal method to fill nodatas, this is what it would look like:

[image: image with filled regions]

This was quick and dirty and other methods likely exist but would probably look equally odd. Perhaps numpy.nan_to_num is another solution if you don't have gdal.

In case you're curious...here's the code (continues from previous code block):

```
import gdal
ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', zi.shape[1], zi.shape[0], 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)
in_band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
in_band.SetNoDataValue(-9999)
in_band.FlushCache()

raster_data = np.copy(zi)
raster_data[np.isnan(zi)] = -9999

in_band.WriteArray(raster_data)

#this line takes a while to run...grab a coffee
result = gdal.FillNodata(in_band, None, maxSearchDist=20000, smoothingIterations=0)
in_band.FlushCache()

newz = in_band.ReadAsArray()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.axis((x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))

#added the 'extend' parameter as per documentation of plt.contourf
#https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html
plt.contourf(xi, yi, newz, levels=[1,2,3,4,5,6], cmap=cmap, extend='both')
plt.plot(x, y,'k.')

plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to believe there are methods that won't make it so odd. 
Nevertheless, that is the answer I as hoping to get. 
Thanks to warped and makis as well

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib
colors = ['red','green','blue','purple','black', 'coral']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.scatter(x, y, c = z, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! Is there a way to add contourf / heatmap to the scatter? So the graph will contain interpolated "regions" of data (coloured areas in my first pic)?

Answer (score 1):

looking at `df.describe()`:

```
            id           Y              X           cluster
    count   706.000000  706.000000      706.000000  706.000000
    mean    357.035411  18401.784703    3217.385269 3.002833
    std     205.912934  46147.403750    950.665697  0.532616
    min     1.000000    278.000000      328.000000  1.000000
    25%     178.500000  3546.000000     2498.500000 3.000000
    50%     358.500000  6869.500000     3574.000000 3.000000
    75%     534.750000  17169.000000    3997.500000 3.000000
    max     712.000000  877392.000000   4321.000000 6.000000
```

`X` is between 328 and 4321, `Y` is between 278 and 887392.

your lines

> ```
> xi = yi = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01) 
> xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
> ```

create a grid with x,y values between zero and one. 
So, you are trying to interpolate using data that is very far away from your grid.

Setting

```
xi = np.arange(0, np.max(x), 0.1)
yi = np.arange(0, np.max(y), 0.1)

xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
```

and leaving out the `np.arange...`in `plt.contour`:

> ```
> fig = plt.figure()
> ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
> ax.axis((x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
> plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, cmap='coolwarm') # <-- removed np.arange()
> plt.plot(x,y,'k.')
> plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=16)
> plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=16)
> plt.show()
> ```

[image]

using `levels` to draw contours:
    plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=[1,2,3,4,5,6], cmap='coolwarm')

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Finally, the colours! :)
Is there a way to interpolate colours to the unfilled white area? 

And how do you think, is it possible to make coloured areas less... "messy"? Like in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607550/putting-limits-to-x-y-z-interpolated-heatmap-in-matplotlib